# Compare struct to a constant in C

Tags: c

I am trying to make a custom string class. Stuck on the a problem where I need to compare by struct to a constant string

Example

```
    typedef struct{
      char *val;
    } STRING;

    int func (STRING* compare){
      if ( compare == "a string" ){
        return 1;
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `strcmp(compare->val, "a string") == 0`

Comment: @Barmar `overload` + `C` does not compute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use strcmp. To keep with returning 1 if equal:

```
int func (STRING* compare){
  if ( strcmp(compare, "a string" ) == 0) 
    return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with `struct` in C, since you don't have object oriented features, it's good to encapsulate the behavior or operations on such `struct` inside methods.

Since your `STRING` type contains a pointer that I guess should be owned by the instance then you could provide 3 methods to manage allocation, decallocation and comparison of `STRING` objects, for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct {
    char* val;
} STRING;

STRING string_alloc(const char* val) {
    STRING string;
    string.val = malloc(strlen(val)+1);
    strcpy(string.val, val);
    return string;
}

void string_free(STRING* string) {
    free(string->val);
}

bool string_compare(const STRING* str1, const STRING* str2) {
    return strcmp(str1->val, str2->val) == 0;
}

int main(void) {
    STRING string = string_alloc("foo");
    STRING string2 = string_alloc("foo");

    printf("Are equal: %s\n", string_compare(&string, &string2) ? "true" : "false");

    string_free(&string);
    string_free(&string2);

    return 0;
}
```

In this way you are able to encapsulate the comparison behavior inside a method and alter it if you need to alter the structure of the `struct`  (eg adding fields, removing fields) without touching anything else of the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct{
    char *val;
} STRING;

int cmp(const STRING *a)
{
    return strcmp(a->val, "a string");
}
```

You need `strcmp` for string comparison. == compares addresses.

Comment: actually this is the opposite o what the OP wanted since `strcmp` returns 0 if the two strings are equal.

Comment: @Jack  OP's post is ambiguous on that point, yet you are likely correct.