# C quote constant returns a struct

Tags: c

I previously asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37449439/compare-struct-to-a-constant-in-c) but I guess I was not specific enough

I need a way to return a custom `struct` instead of char* when defining a constant string, for example:

```
typedef struct{
  char *value;
  int length;
} string;

string *a;
a = "abc" //Sets a->value to "abc" and length to 3 ("abc" return string instead of char*)
```

Comment: `from using quotes`..really?

Comment: If you told us why, we might be able to find a better solution. If you're writing your own improved string library, consider using one of the many existing ones. [Gnome Lib's Strings](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Strings.html), for example.

Comment: The gchar from the gtk source code works well, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that you can just make a type that is equal to char like this:

```
typedef char string;

string *a = "abc"; 
//Doesn't address length but just have a separate function:
int get_len ( string *in ){
  return strlen(in);
}
```

Got this from [here](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/unstable/glib-Basic-Types.html#gchar)

Answer (score 2):

If this were C++, you could use operator overloading and define a = function, but this is C, so no operator overloading. However you can get through this by just writing an "equals()" or "set()" function.

Comment: thx, i started as a c++ programmer so i seem to forget that C lacks many of the features from c++

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking to default initialize it then you can change how it is assigned:

```
string a = {"abc", 4};
```

Here is a live example: http://ideone.com/ERU4yM

If you need to change the string after its decleration then you will need to write some form of `set` function.